# IOS App uploaded successfully on iOS app store but not visible in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode7, app-store-connect

l am a newbie in IOS App development however l created an app and followed all steps of certificates signing and provisional profile for distribution. l created an archive in Xcode 7, under Organizer and it uploaded successfully on ios app store. But when l go to iTunes Connect under Build l cant see the "+" sign and the build is not visible. l have tried re uploading many time but its of no help.. Please help even with screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you upload your app,it will take a while to see the app in build.but you can see the app in Activity,the status should be processing.
Wait a moment(about 10minutes),after the processing step is done, you will see your app.

Comment: ...thank for your response. Under Activity l also cant see any build or application it is saying "Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later." l also cant see the processing step

Comment: maybe try to upload again?I once run into this,after uploading the app for one more time, I find two app in Activity.I don't why,maybe this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you guys l have managed to upload it. l just had to use Application Loader and it gave me an error to do with App Icons that l managed to fix.So l have uploaded successfully now

Answer (score 1):

As Pranay suggested, it generally takes some time to reflect in iTunes Connect portal.

You can check your uploaded builds under **My Apps -> Activity -> All Builds** section in iTunes Connect. All the uploaded binaries from Xcode/Application Loader are listed there. You can also check whether your binary is in "under processing" state or not.

Also, please make sure you see the successful upload confirmation page (without any error) while uploading your IPA file from Xcode/Application Loader.

Comment: Thank you.. It uploads successfully without any errors. What is shocking me is l have uploaded it also a few days ago and l also cant  see it under My Apps -> Activity -> All Builds section

Comment: That's really strange!! Please make sure you are logging into iTunes Connect with correct entitlements. I am not sure why this could happen.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post a screenshot of your upload confirmation page as well.

Comment: Thank you guys l have managed to upload it. l just had to use Application Loader and it gave me an error to do with App Icons that l managed to fix.So l have uploaded successfully now

Comment: Yeah!! Application Loader provides more descriptive interface and activity reporting as compared to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It would take time for processing. The build is not visible until the **Processing** step is in progress. It's depend on the size of the app.You can check the status in iTunesConnect Activity. For [more details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html)

If still it doesn't worked, try to upload the build using **Application Loader**.

Comment: thank for your response. Under Activity l also cant see any build or application it is saying "Submit your builds using Xcode 6 or later, or Application Loader 3.0 or later."

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar issue, found several threads saying to check your email. Apparently, rather than let you know immediately about an issue, they email any issues to you. Hope this helps.